# How do I get a MEF Directory catalog looking at the same directory for both the Servicelayer and DAL?

Tags: plugins, mef

I'm using MEF to add plugins to our DAL which is used by our WebApp. This works fine, but when  our service layer references the DAL, it's looking for plugins in \ServiceLayer\Plugins\
rather than \WebSite\Plugins\ (which makes sense are we're using a relative path. {DirectoryCatalog (Path="plugins/")}.

The problem is if we use an absolute path it refuses to load the plugins from both the SL and the DAL, which I believe is because the path isn't within the same directory or subdiectory of the App loading the plugins(?). How can I get them to both load plugins from one folder?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are adding catalogs to the container, where that call is taking place and the directory structure? Also, just to be clear your serviceLayer is not an application of any sort, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually do this. Solution was to have a copy of the DLLs, one set in the web app folder, another in the service layer folder