# Managed Extensibility Framework

Tags: c#, service, mef

I'm creating a Service for my organization that will be installed on hundreds of computers. The Implementation of it may need to change over time. After watching and read a bit about MEF I'm still a little lost. Is MEF a good soulution for say if I wanted to Drop a dll into the service folder and have that service pick up the changes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pick up the changes"? Do you mean you want to add modules to the application without recompiling it? Or change the application without restarting it? Or something else?

Comment: I want to change the application without compiling, removing the service, reinstalling the service. With over a 100 install this is a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done quite a bit with MEF.  Yes, MEF will do what you're looking for, with a caveat...

- You *can* discover and load in a new DLL at runtime
- However, it loads into the same App domain as your main application so,
- You *can't* unload or change the DLL without restarting your application

If that last point is a problem, consider MAF (although it's much heavier).  But in MAF, it will load your extensions into a separate app domain.

Your other option is just to spawn off another process to handle the request, and pass command line parameters to it.

Comment: Thank you for Clarifying. Restarting should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using VS2010 i recommend you try first Click Once. It gives you the setup.exe but also gives you an HTML file (and other files), wich you can upload to an IIS server or an FTP site, or even to a shared folder over your local network. The thing is, when you configure your deployment you can tell the installer to auto-update all clientes directly from the site (the HTML file, ftp or lan shared folder). When user starts the application it will connect to the site and ask for an update if it exists, and if it does, the application will self-update. If you want to deploy an update, you only need to upload again the HTML file and all other files in the folder.

Check out this links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953320.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications.aspx

Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this if you have your service logic in a separated class library and you got the needed contract interfaces in another class library. Then you can create a directory catalog and import your service implementation with MEF (you only need to reference to the contract interfaces assembly). Then you can pick up the new dll/service implementation if changed. You only need a directory watcher (FileSystemWatcher), then you have to call your catalog's refresh method when directory watcher fires. In theory it should work, but it's just an idea. :) Anyway, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert about MEF. Documentation says Mef is all about making plug-in based systems. so your system expects some interfaces and MEF makes easy to import classes implemented these interfaces to your system.your case seems suitable for this.  MEF has directory catalog and by using catalogs you can import types/dlls runtime.

[How do I get a MEF Directory catalog looking at the same directory for both the Servicelayer and DAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564523/how-do-i-get-a-mef-directory-catalog-looking-at-the-same-directory-for-both-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/). From what I understand, they are two different frameworks to do pretty much the same thing. Prism allows you to create modules by having a class in a dll that implements the IModule interface. You can just drag and drop dlls into a folder this way just like in MEF. You can statically or dynamically load modules, and do a bunch of other things I don't even know about.

Prism also has other features bundled with it, i.e. the Unity dependency injection container (which I like to call "The Magical Black Box"), a neat event and command system, etc. I'm sure MEF has all these things too.