# Relative paths, MEF Directory Catalog and symlinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, symlink

Currently I have the same problem as: [How do I get a MEF Directory catalog looking at the same directory for both the Servicelayer and DAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564523/how-do-i-get-a-mef-directory-catalog-looking-at-the-same-directory-for-both-the).

I have a service say `serviceWithMEF` that initialises an MEF container. If this service is consumed by the web application project in the same solution, a relative path for the catalog such as `..\..\Extensions` will search for the dll's two folders up from the web's root folder. However, if some other non-web project in the solution consumes it, it looks for the Extensions directory two folders up from \Debug\Bin instead.

I would like all projects in the same solution to look for the Extensions directory in the same place, without using absolute paths. `serviceWithMEF` currently gets the path `..\..\Extensions\` from the globalsettings.xml.

One possible solution I had was to create a symlink called 'Extensions' in all the projects folders and have the links point to the Extensions directory that the web application uses. However MEF doesn't seem to be treating the symlink as a directory.

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Config.ExtensionPath));
```

leaves me with an empty catalog if I have a symlink that was created with `mklink /D Extensions ..\..\Extensions`, instead of an actual directory.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: By changing the symlink from a symbolic link to a junction seems to work. Strange..

Comment: See [this question/answer](http://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link) on superuser.com.